# UITableView reloadData() after Facebook login is completed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

My app allows the user to log in via Facebook. Pressing the login button redirects the user to Safari/Facebook app(FBSDK default setting). When the login is completed, the user is redirected back to my app. During an active Facebook session, the user is supposed to see the profile picture and username from Facebook presented in a `UITavleView` cell. The problem is that the cell is not updated after redirection and I need to call `tableView.reloadData()` manually after the login procedure in order for the table to appear correctly.

I've tried to override the `ViewController's` `viewDidAppear()` method but the transition between apps does not call on this method. I also tried to have a timer that reloads table data every x seconds but that is not a real solution to my problem. I also thought about using some of the app delegate's methods but that also seems like a bad practise. Anyone got a clue? I tried to look in FBSDK documentation for a method similar to `UIWebView's` `didFinishLoading()` but didn't find anything of value.

Comment: Please check your table view delegate is connected or not?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the table contains more cells, all working fine. The delegate is connected, the manual reloadData() call wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: If facebook is redirecting you to safari then you should consider alternatives because there have many instances of app rejection because of this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facebook Login Delegate methods.If login is successful then reload tableview data

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Unexpected login error: %@", error);
    NSString *alertMessage = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedDescriptionKey] ?: @"There was a problem logging in. Please try again later.";
    NSString *alertTitle = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedTitleKey] ?: @"Oops";
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                message:alertMessage
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
} else {
     NSLog(@"Success login and Reload Tableview data");
}
}
```

don't forget to set ur Facebook button delegate

```
self.loginBut.delegate=self;
```

Answer (score 1):

Trusting user goes out of your app and login to FB and then come back, you can utilize AppDelegate method `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)iApplication` to fire a local notification and listen to that in your View Controller to trigger table reload.

**EDIT:**

You can directly register for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in your view controller' `loadView` method. But please ensure to remove observer when view is unloading or deallocating.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: “applicationBecameActive:",
    name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification,
    object: nil)

@objc func applicationBecameActive(notification: NSNotification){     
    //reload your table here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        //Post notification to reload after came from login
    }
    else {
        // Try to login first
    }

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation
            ];
}
```